# Getting the error of POST method from another PHP file

Tags: php, ajax, json

I've been searching for answers but still, i don't know how to do it. To be honest, i am not that good at programming and I'm still at the process of learning.

below is my code :

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "process.php",
data: {
postid: post_id
},
success: function(){
document.getElementById('processed').innerHTML = post_id;
...
```

I don't have a problem with that, its just that i want to get the error on process.php (if there's any).

process.php code where i want to get the error :

```
  if($result){
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $m = $row['processedID'];
            $id = trim($_POST ['postid']);
        try {
            ..something...
      }
       catch (APIHandle $e) {
            $output .= "<p>'". $row['name'] . "' processing failed</p>";
         }
}
}
```

i want to get this line :

```
 $output .= "<p>'". $row['name'] . "' processing failed</p>";
```

and show it on my first php file as an error and output it as a text.
For example, the user clicks a button , it checks for the input and output the error if there's any using those codes.

Thank you for your help!

***EDIT!***
i am now using the code provided by andy because it handles the error and it gives me an option on what to do  if error occurs. the problem is i don't know how to work with it using textfields / form items.
here is my updated code :

```
    var textfieldvalue = $("#text").val();
    var post_id = textfieldvalue;
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                postid: post_id
            },
            success: function(result){
                 if (result.error) {
                    $('#accesserror').show();
                    $('#error').html(result.error).show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#loading").hide();
                    $("#processor").show();

                }
```

i know that there is something wrong with this.
please? this is the last time that i will ask for help with this.
thank you and all your answers will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to get the message once the ajax call returns?

Comment: have you checked that are you getting the $_POST ['postid'] on process.php ??

Comment: @UmairIqbal, yes. that is what i want to do

Comment: @HarshalMahajan, yes, those codes are working. its just that i want to show the errors.

Comment: @UmairIqbal, ok. im trying all the answers

Answer (score 0):

Then you should return the `$output` containing the error as `json_encoded()` as you are probably doing with your normal results. You could also encode an array with several error messages.

Comment: i think i should study more, providing the fact that i  don't know what is "json_encoded()".

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "process.php",
  data: {
  postid: post_id
  },
  success: function(data){
  document.getElementById('processed').innerHTML = data;
  }
```

Your process.php

```
  if($result){
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $m = $row['processedID'];
        $id = trim($_POST ['postid']);
    try {
        ..something...
    }
    catch (APIHandle $e) {
        echo $output .= "<p>'". $row['name'] . "' processing failed</p>";
     }
  }
```

if your code goes to catch in process.php it wqill return the output and in ajax dispay that output

Comment: thnk you! i'll try it know :)

Comment: let me know if it works... If not I can provide you another solution

Comment: @UmairIqbal Shouldn't it be `echo "<p>'". $row['name'] . "' processing failed</p>";`?

Comment: $output = "<p>" .$row['name']. "processing failed</p>";
echo $output;

Comment: @UmairIqbal, ok, but i got a problem testing the code. i can't test it with my computer. i'll update you if it worked ok?

Comment: you can check it via firebug and see the response of your ajax. whenever you can test it. I am here to help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is JSON. Then you can check if the `error` field is empty and show an error if it is not. Try something like the below.

```
if($result) {
    $result = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $m = $row['processedID'];
        $id = trim($_POST ['postid']);

        try {
            // something
        }
        catch (APIHandle $e) {
            $result['error'] = 'Processing failed!';
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        postid: post_id
    },

    success: function(result){
        // There was an error
        if (result.error) {
            $('#error').html(result.error).show();
        }

        // No error
        else {
            // Something
        }
    }
});
```

Then you can simply return other data in `$result['something_else']` and show that if there was no error. Also, this solution gives you a lot of flexibility to choose where you want to show your data. For instance, you may want to show your error somewhere else than the rest of the data you return from PHP. If you just echo the data out in PHP, you are forced to show it at the same place, and then you have to rely on CSS to change the positioning.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your help! gosh, lots of good answers in an instant!

Comment: what if there are more than one error, does this shows it all?

Comment: @NishaLeine Then you can return an array of errors from PHP and loop through them in jQuery. I wrote an [answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237986/load-more-getting-10-more-results/12238038#12238038) yesterday showing how to do this. Alternatively, a less pretty but easier solution is to just put all of your errors in your error string, like this: `$result['error'] .= 'Another error';`

Comment: @NishaLeine Please accept the answer if you used this approach and it worked. Thanks.